# Is 'transition' an invalid resource directory name on Android?

Tags: android

I make the ApiDemos project from Android Sample Project. Unfortunately, the project complains `invalid resource directory name  transition  /ApiDemos/res   line 1  Android AAPT Problem`.

My Eclipse is Version: Juno Service Release 2 and JDK 7. The ADT plugin is V22.6.0. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [`transition`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Transition.html) resources are valid as of API 19.

To get rid of the error, make your build SDK API level 19 or higher.

To do that, in Eclipse/ADT, either

- open Project Properties, go to Android and select Project Build Target as API 19, or
- edit `project.properties` at project root and edit `target` to e.g. `android-19`

Of course, you will have to have SDK 19 installed with SDK Manager and have up-to-date build tools installed.

Comment: Thanks @laalto. I installed build SDK Platform-tools level 19, also chose the `android-19`(Android4.2.2), but the error exists still.

Comment: Sorry @laalto. I make mistake Platform-tools with Build-tools. Now I update the build tools to level 19.0.3 and the problem is solved. Thanks for your answers again.

Answer (score 0):

In case another bonehead like me comes here: I didn't have version 19 of the API installed :P

Open up your SDK manager and download any necessary version. I just had the latest version installed (22?).

Also, this was for Xamarin for me. But it could be the case for others, too.